# PHP/MySQL dropdown list with multiple columns, trouble with syntax

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu, alias

I'm trying to get a drop down list to display multiple columns from a table, and for the selected row's primary id to be stored in the variable name.

I get a list of rows if I drop the CONCAT function and SELECT a single column, but I can't figure out how to select more than one. What am I doing wrong?

```
<li>
    <?php 
    $sql="SELECT CONCAT(county, ' ',municipality, ' ',park), id FROM mtmg.locality";
    $result=mysql_query($sql, $connection);

    echo '<label for="county_municipality_park">County, Municipality, Park</label>';
    echo '<select  id="county_municipality_park" name="county_municipality_park">';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {echo '<option value="'.$row['county,municipality,park'].'">'.$row['county,municipality,park'].'</option>';}
    echo mysql_error();

    echo '</select>';
    ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your CONCAT() function an alias, something like

```
SELECT CONCAT(county, ' ',municipality, ' ',park) as county_municipality_park, id FROM ...
```

and then reference it as such in the `$row` array, i.e. `$row['county_municipality_park']`.

Comment: @SabeenMalik @spanky Great explanation! One more thing, this only works if all values are non-null. Is there any way to show partial results?

Comment: I might select county, municipality, and park separately, and then reference them all together in PHP. Once it gets put into the $row array, PHP will treate NULL and blank values the same, so instead of echoing `$row['county_municipality_park']` you could echo `$row['county'].' '.$row['municipality'].' '.$row['park']`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for. One last thing, I haven't been able to test this yet, but based on the current query: `$sql="SELECT county, municipality, park, id FROM mtmg.locality";`, is everything but the last value after SELECT displayed, the final value (id) to be stored in $_POST['county_municipality_park']? I have to learn PHP/MySQL as I go along with my job, so this isn't apparent to me yet.

Comment: You can display any of the SELECTed fields. You've used `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` to turn them into an array called `$row`, so any of them can be called from there, like $row['id'], $row['municipality'], etc. Things get stored in $_POST when you use them as values for `input` items in HTML and then post the data using a <form> with a post method. This is really too much to write about in a comment. I suggest you look into some tutorials!

Comment: OK thanks! I've figured it all out with your help. I should be putting: `echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['county'].', '.$row['municipality'].', '.$row['park'].'</option>'` to get what I want. I should have known that, but it wasn't apparent to me until now. I initially wrote the form in openoffice base, and I thought it was something in the SQL syntax that differentiated displayed and stored data.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT(county, ' ',municipality, ' ',park) as location , id FROM mtmg.locality";
```

and then use `$row['location']`